# NullPointerException access bean from property plugin

Tags: java, spring, grails

Good afternoon guys, I got an error but can not remedy. 
I have a property plugin with various beans and I access this beans from a Grails App, but when I trying to access the bean 'queueMessageSender', i have e NullPointerException.

Inside my plugin I have this line:

```
def doWithSpring = { 
queueMessageSender(QueueMessageSenderImp) {
                jmsTemplate = ref('jmsTemplate')
                queue = ref('queue')
            }
}
```

Using the Grails console, I have the following scenario:

```
groovy> assert ctx.containsBeanDefinition('queueMessageSender') == true 
groovy> ctx.getBean('queueMessageSender') 

Result: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$toString.call(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.ui.Console.finishNormal(Console.groovy:759)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:727)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1147)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17_closure32.doCall(Console.groovy:955)
    at groovy.ui.Console$_runScriptImpl_closure17_closure32.doCall(Console.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:490)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

[Error in grails application]

```
| Error java.lang.NullPointerException
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at br.com.qreserva.portal.services.IntegracaoService$_atualizarDisponibilidade_closure6.doCall(IntegracaoService.groovy:435)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
| Error     at br.com.qreserva.portal.services.IntegracaoService$_atualizarDisponibilidade_closure6.call(IntegracaoService.groovy)
| Error     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
| Error     at br.com.qreserva.portal.services.IntegracaoService$_atualizarDisponibilidade_closure6.call(IntegracaoService.groovy)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1326)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1298)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$148.invoke(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at br.com.qreserva.portal.services.IntegracaoService.atualizarDisponibilidade(IntegracaoService.groovy:423)
| Error     at br.com.qreserva.portal.services.IntegracaoService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$c7ce785a.invoke(<generated>)
| Error     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
| Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
| Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
| Error     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
| Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
| Error     at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
| Error     at br.com.qreserva.portal.services.IntegracaoService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$771a8c24.atualizarDisponibilidade(<generated>)
| Error     at br.com.qreserva.portal.services.IntegracaoService$atualizarDisponibilidade.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
| Error     at br.com.qreserva.portal.controllers.ReservaController.salvarDadosReserva(ReservaController.groovy:730)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper.invoke(MixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:69)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:343)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.executeAction(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:226)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:192)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.handleURI(AbstractGrailsControllerHelper.java:116)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController.handleRequest(SimpleGrailsController.java:72)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:328)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
| Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
| Error     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:314)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:279)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:270)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:222)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:206)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:152)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:66)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
| Error     at org.grails.plugin.resource.DevModeSanityFilter.doFilter(DevModeSanityFilter.groovy:45)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.super$3$doFilterHttp(GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor739.invoke(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
| Error     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
| Error     at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:128)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(GrailsAuthenticationProcessingFilter.groovy:56)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.FixRedirectLogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilterFactoryBean.groovy)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
| Error     at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
| Error     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
| Error     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
| Error     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
| Error     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
| Error     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
| Error     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Does anyone have an idea of how the bean can be in the context, but not be able to access it?

Comment: I alter the message. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: The error message looks like it may have come from the console but the prompt "groovy >" looks like you may have been entering commands from the shell.  Did that exception come from the shell or the console?

Comment: I think I see now.  The text above is copied from the output of the console, those are not prompts where you were typing.  My mistake.

Comment: The latest edit to the question allows it to make more sense.  What is at line 435 of IntegracaoService.groovy?

Comment: queueMessageSender.send(avail)

Comment: There is some other piece of the puzzle that isn't represented in the description which will explain what is going on. If you can reproduce in a sample app which you can share I will be happy to take a look.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/eduardofb/dda70f7a83ea5523405b#file-errorbeancreation This is an example of use.

Comment: It isn't clear to me from looking at that why `queueMesageSender.send` is ever invoked as a result of just calling `getBean`.  Seeing that happen in a running app would make this trivial to address.

Comment: As I said before, i fyou can reproduce in a sample app which you can share I will be happy to address it.  If not, maybe someone else will be able to just look at the stack and sort it out for you.  Best of luck.